# Reading a binary file with IDL

Tags: c, idl-programming-language

I have an IDL routine that reads a binary data file. However, on this occasion, i'm getting "READU: End of file encountered. Unit 2, File: data.dat".

Instead of destroying the binary file and re-creating it. Is this problem surmountable? What IDL code could I use to allow me to read the binary file? The binary file was created by a C function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "IDL"?

Comment: @Dai Almost certain that IDL refers to [IDL (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29), I changed the tag to reflect that.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the contents of the file? What did your C code write into it? Could you paste your IDL code that reads it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I'm assuming the binary file has a defined structure.  You can probably use `fstat()` and `eof()` to get around this.  For example:

```
openr, lun, 'file.bin', /get_lun
fs = fstat(lun)

len = fs.size / n_bytes_in_data_structure
for i = 0L, len - 1 do begin
    readu, lun, var
    ...
```

If you don't know the size of your data structures or if you want to check that there's a sufficient number of bytes before a read, you can use `fs.cur_ptr` (after a call to `fstat()`, of course) or `eof(lun)`.